# В консоль все равно выводится ошибка при использовании try catch в fetch

Tags: javascript, fetch, try-catch

В консоль выводится сообщение об ошибке :

> send_methods.js:27 POST http://localhost/foo 400 (Bad Request)

Хотя пробую ее отловить:

```js
export const SendPostMethod = async (path, body, callback, returnerror) => {
    try {
        const response = await fetch(path, {
            credentials: 'same-origin',
            method: 'POST',
            body: body
        });
        if (response.ok && response.status === 200) {               
           if (callback) {
              callback(await response.text()); 
           }                
        } else {
            throw(await response.text());
        }
    } catch (err) {
        if(returnerror) {
            return returnerror(err);
        }
    }
};
```

Или все равно будет в консоле ошибка?

Comment: Ошибка именно запроса будет всегда выводиться.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Это не ошибка, а уведомление об http-запросе. Оно будет выводиться независимо от обработки.